Ubuntu 20.04 : Unable to load the ‘nvidia-drm’ kernel
I failed to install the Nvidia driver using NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.154.05.run on my Ubuntu 20.04 system this morning.
At the end of the installation, an error occurs:
ERROR: Unable to load the 'Nvidia-drm' kernel module.

I had installed the same NVIDIA driver before until I updated the Linux kernel from 5.4.0 to 5.15.0, now the computer cannot use GUI, only a command line is available. So I type all the information here word by word using my mobile phone. (a little inconvenient though)
This is an emergency and I hope somebody can help me.
System information
$ uname -sr
Linux 5.15.0-101-generic

$ lsb-release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

If you need more info, I will reply in real-time

Just try reinstalling using apt, that often brings the system back to a usable (or GUI capable rather) state: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535

It seems that the NVIDIA driver was blacklisted for some reason, I resolved it in this way:
sudo prime-select nvidia

run
grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/*

to find a file containing
blacklist nvidia
and remove it,
then run
sudo update-initramfs -u

and reboot.

refs: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/510-54-rtx3090-ubuntu-20-04-unable-to-load-the-nvidia-drm-kernel-module/204261/2
